# Regex for not allowing 0,0.0,0.000 etc

Tags: regex

I have below validation working fine. But want to restrict zero values.

I would like to restrict entering `0` or `0.0` or `0.00`.

Valid values are `0.01` to `1,234,567.99`

```js
$.validator.addMethod("verifyDecimalVal", function(value, element) {    
    return this.optional(element) || value == value.match(/^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[\s\.,]\d{3})+)(?:[\.,]\d+)?$/);
},"Please enter valid amount");
```

Comment: Add `(?!0.?0*$)` after `^` in your regex. Or `(?=.*[1-9])`

Comment: Can I ask you one more request ? - I have another regex for validating the values that is 1 to 100 including decimals ex : 1, 1.05, 1.20 etc up to 99.99. below regex is working except for 100  - /^(?=.*[1-9])\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/. I want to allow 100 as well.

Comment: Just add `|^100$`, no need to reinvent anything.

Comment: is this look correct ? : /^(?=.*[1-9])\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{0,2})?|^100$/

Comment: You've lost `$` before the `|`, but otherwise - yes.

Comment: How about this : /^(?=.*[1-9])\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$|^100/